# use Map in typescript with added fields

Tags: typescript

I have a small problem. I have data like this:
["1112234", "S1044N", "A1041DS"]

I would like to use Map to create new array from this but for every field i would like some additional properties.

I tried something like:

```
 let newArray: SomeDataType= [];
     newArray=data.map((articleNumber) => {});
```

My problem is that i don't know how to add populate new array with data from old and properties from SomeDataType. I don't want to use loops but do it with map.

My new array should have field articleNumber from lda array , articleName , articlePrice from newArray. But iam not sure how to do that.

Anybody have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface SomeDataType {
    articleNumber: string;
    articleName: string;
    articlePrice: number;
}

const data: Array<string> = ["1112234", "S1044N", "A1041DS"];
const newArray: Array<SomeDataType> = data.map(articleNumber => {
    return {
        articleNumber: articleNumber,
        articleName: "Article",
        articlePrice: 50
    }; 
})
```

Comment: Thank you Younes Guarssifi :)

Comment: Just one more question if i would want to calculate price in article price property could i do it? like articlePrice: { const price= 25, return price} something like that?

Comment: First calculate the price (before the return statement) and store it in a variable, then put it in the returned object. `const price = /*calculation here*/; return {articleNumber...`